# Creating a self-contained installation file for pymssql for CentOS

Tags: centos, software-installation, python

I'm trying to deploy a Python application on a machine that due to system and organisation requirements can't have `gcc` installed on it, so I need to create a self-contained installation file for `pymssql` (normally it requires `FreeTDS` and `gcc gcc-c++`).

I've managed to get rid of the `FreeTDS` requirement by using
`export PYMSSQL_BUILD_WITH_BUNDLED_FREETDS=1` before installing `pymssql`, but it still fails on the `gcc` requirement.

Is there any way to pre-compile `pymssql` so it can be deployed and installed on a machine with no dependency on neither `FreeTDS` nor `gcc`?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using the CentOS system Python as it would be difficult to install a different (up-to-date) python without access to `gcc`.

Setup a VM (e.g. in VirtualBox) with the exact same CentOS version, hosted on a different machine. In that VM install the required `gcc`, and install [`virtualenv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) ( I recommend doing that from source, the one you can install with your package manager is quite often outdated).

On the VM, create a virtual environment e.g. with `virtualenv /opt/util/pymssql`, this virtual environment will have references to the real python but since you are going to move it to an equivalent CentOS, that is ok.

Activate the environment (  `source /opt/util/pymssql/bin/activate` ) and use `pip` to install all the libraries that you need.

When all is installed and working, `tar` the `/opt/util/pymssql` and its subdirectories and put it on the "real" CentOS machine **in the same location**. That should give you working code without a compiler on the "real" machine.

The actual directory (in the example `/opt/util/pymssql`) for the virtual environment is not important, but you have to use the path that will be used on the "real" machine, some of the files in the virtual env will have the path hardcoded.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're trying to reinvent the wheel, or in this case RPM packages.

Comment: @jsbillings I have provided RPMs for SuSE distributions and getting that to work is at least a magnitude more effort than creating a one-off virtualenv as described above. But feel free to describe the steps on how to do this based on creating an RPM

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is to build your own CentOS package.  It looks like there was, at one time, a package for pymssql, but it was abandoned because of lack of maintainers, but you could use the spec file in Fedora's git repo as a starting point:

http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/rpms/pymssql.git/tree/pymssql.spec

Answer (score 0):

Set up VM with same OS and install needed tools (gcc) as Anthon suggests but instead of creating and zipping virtualenv (which is kind of a hack) build binary wheel and install this wheel in target system.

Related:
[How to avoid building C library with my python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31380578/95735)
[Build a wheel/egg and all dependencies for a python project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26059111/95735)